# imacros invalid property id

Tags: javascript, loops, syntax, imacros

Hi Im trying to loop through a csv and store each line in a JavaScript variable.

```
 var y = {{!COL1}};
```

What is the proper approach considering

```
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\imacros\\demo.csv" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for iMacros in JavaScript:

```
var lines = read_file('C:\\imacros\\demo.csv');
for(var i=0;i<lines.length; i++){
    alert(i + "("+lines[i].length+"): " + lines[i]);
}

function read_file(csv_file_name){
    const CRLF = "\r\n";
    const LF = "\n";
    var lines = new Array();
    var file_i = imns.FIO.openNode(csv_file_name);
    var text = imns.FIO.readTextFile(file_i);
    var eol = (text.indexOf(CRLF) == -1) ? LF : CRLF;
    lines = text.split(eol);
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Thanks will have a look at it and get back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a typical solution:

```
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\imacros\\demo.csv" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
macro += "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + "\n";
// ...
var y = iimGetExtract();
```

Answer (score 0):

An array is the best thing to use to store lists of things.  Create your array like this:

```
var lines= [];
```

Then in your loop that reads the lines, do this:

```
lines.push(theLineIJustRead);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.The line read in imacros format is referred to as !COL1 how do I get JavaScript to transcribe that ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question- I don't have any knowledge of iMacros.

Comment: Ah i see. Thanks all the same.